# r - Text alignment in columns for head() in the console

Tags: r, center, text-alignment

r - How do I get the text in each column of my table to align to the center when I head() data in the console?

My goal is for my table to look like this:

```
Pclass   agecat    Sex      N     survivors   perc_survived
 <int>   <fctr>    <chr>   <int>     <int>         <dbl>
   1    Under 15  female     2         1        50.000000
   1    Under 15    male     3         3       100.000000
   1    15 to 50  female    70        68        97.142857
   1    15 to 50    male    72        32        44.444444
   1    Over 50   female    13        13       100.000000
   1    Over 50     male    26         5        19.230769
```

Currently, my table looks like this:

```
> head (titanic_4)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   Pclass, agecat [3]
  Pclass   agecat    Sex     N survivors perc_survived
   <int>   <fctr>  <chr> <int>     <int>         <dbl>
1      1 Under 15 female     2         1     50.000000
2      1 Under 15   male     3         3    100.000000
3      1 15 to 50 female    70        68     97.142857
4      1 15 to 50   male    72        32     44.444444
5      1  Over 50 female    13        13    100.000000
6      1  Over 50   male    26         5     19.230769
```

This is my code:

```
library(dplyr)
titanic_4 <- titanic %>% 
  select(Survived, Pclass, Age, Sex) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Age)) %>%
  mutate(agecat = cut(Age, breaks = c(0, 14.99, 50, 150), 
                      include.lowest = TRUE,
                      labels = c("Under 15", "15 to 50",
                                 "Over 50"))) %>%
  group_by(Pclass,agecat,Sex) %>%
  summarize(N=n(), survivors = sum(Survived))%>%
  mutate(perc_survived = survivors/N*100)

head (titanic_4)
```

Comment: Are you talking about printing in the console, or in a `knitr` document, or something else?

Comment: Thank you for your question.  I edited the post to reflect your comment. I am wondering how to change the appearance of the table while using head() in the console.

Comment: I think you'd need to write a custom print function. `print.data.frame` lets you set right-alignment to `TRUE` (the default) or `FALSE` (for left-alignment, but that doesn't have a center option. You could overwrite `print.data.frame` with custom behavior. `dplyr`'s `tbl` objects have their own print function, so if you're using `dplyr` a lot, that's the method you should overwrite instead (see `print.tbl_df` in the `tibble` package) - which could be easier because it uses `format`, which does have a `centre` justify option, though only for character vectors.

Comment: [You can see the print.tbl` function here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/blob/master/R/tbl-df.r)